# Doing a change program for my java class, not sure how to loop the whole program?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Currently I am working on a program in which the user enters a value in cents (so $1.25 would be 125), and the program determines how many coins are given in the fewest amount. I have this working.

What is troubling me is that my professor wants the program to continuously loop until the user enters a value less than 0. I don't know how to do this because every time I try, it only ends up looping once and not displaying the proper amount of coins.

Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakingChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //Prompts user to input the change they recieved.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of change you recieved in coin format. Example: $1.25     would be entered as 125."); 
        int Change = sc.nextInt(); //The value is then stored as an integer named Change.

        int Pennies = 0;
        int Nickels = 0;
        int Dimes = 0;
        int Quarters = 0;

        while (Change < 1){
            System.out.println("Error: Cannot enter a value less than 1!");
            //System.exit(0); //found at http://codingforums.com/java-jsp/69296-%5Bjava%5D-how-end-program.html
        }

        while (Change > 0){ //Runs a loop which determines how many of each coin is used by subtracting the values of the largest first and continuing until 0.
            if (Change >= 25){
                Change -= 25;
                Quarters++;
            }
            else if (Change >= 10){
                Change -= 10;
                Dimes++;
            }
            else if (Change >= 5){
                Change -=5;
                Dimes++;
            }
            else if (Change >= 1){
                Change -= 1;
                Pennies++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println("In total, you should have recieved:");
        System.out.printf("Number of Quarters: %3d  %n", Quarters);
        System.out.printf("Number of Dimes: %6d  %n", Dimes);
        System.out.printf("Number of Nickels: %4d  %n", Nickels);
        System.out.printf("Number of Pennies: %4d  %n", Pennies);
        //Prints out final number of coins used by type of coin.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Scrap your first while loop.  You don't want two loops handling the same thing.  Next, initialize your "Change" variable, but move `sc.nextInt();` inside so that it gets the input every iteration.  Finally, make the loop a do-while loop so it runs at least once (alternatively you could initialize change to 1).

```
int Change = 0;
do{
  Change = sc.nextInt();
  // ...
}
while(Change > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the user how much change they get in the loop. Here is some code below:

```
import java.util.scanner;
public void MakingChange {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int change = 0;
int currentchange = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
change += currentchange;
System.out.println("Enter an amount of change.");
currentchange = in.nextInt();
} while(currentchange > 0);
}
}
System.out.println("Total change: " + change);
```

+1 To Gary for do loop idea.
You get the point.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues in your code, Java naming conventions have variables start with a lower case letter. Next, you could simply loop while the `Scanner.hasNextInt()`. Then, your code would seem to be simpler if you counted the quarters, dimes and nickels (which your nickel counter counts as dimes) in their own loops. So, something like -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String msg = "Please enter the amount of change "
            + "you received in coin format. Example: "
            + "$1.25 would be entered as 125.";
    System.out.println(msg);
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int change = sc.nextInt();
        int pennies = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int quarters = 0;

        if (change < 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: Cannot enter a value less than 1!");
        } else {
            while (change >= 25) {
                change -= 25;
                quarters++;
            }
            while (change >= 10) {
                change -= 10;
                dimes++;
            }
            while (change >= 5) {
                change -= 5;
                nickels++;
            }
            pennies = change;
        }
        System.out.println("In total, you should have recieved:");
        System.out.printf("Number of Quarters: %3d  %n", quarters);
        System.out.printf("Number of Dimes: %6d  %n", dimes);
        System.out.printf("Number of Nickels: %4d  %n", nickels);
        System.out.printf("Number of Pennies: %4d  %n", pennies);
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your loop like so:

```
int change;
while ((change = sc.nextInt()) >= 0) {
    //do code
}
```

Note the lowercase `change`, due to Java naming conventions.

The main problem with your code as-is is that you have two loops, and you'll exit the first immediately if your number is not less than 1 (or loop infinitely if it is less). You did the verification once, then did your program logic. Try using a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop around everything.  The top of the loop will prompt and read the value, and the bottom of the loop will print the output.  But because it is a loop, it will go back and prompt again.  You don't have a loop at that level in the code as given.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakingChange {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //Prompts user to input the change they recieved.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int input = 0;
    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of change you recieved in coin format. Example: $1.25     would be entered as 125."); 
        input= sc.nextInt(); //The value is then stored as an integer named Change.
        if(input<=0) {
         System.out.println("Good Bye");
         break; breaks the loop
        }
    else{
        Change=input;
        int Pennies = 0;
        int Nickels = 0;
        int Dimes = 0;
        int Quarters = 0;

        while (Change > 0){ //Runs a loop which determines how many of each coin is used by subtracting the values of the largest first and continuing until 0.
            if (Change >= 25){
                 Change -= 25;
                Quarters++;
           }
          else if (Change >= 10){
            Change -= 10;
            Dimes++;
          }
          else if (Change >= 5){
            Change -=5;
            Dimes++;
          }
          else if (Change >= 1){
            Change -= 1;
            Pennies++;
          }
       }
       System.out.println("In total, you should have recieved:");
       System.out.printf("Number of Quarters: %3d  %n", Quarters);
       System.out.printf("Number of Dimes: %6d  %n", Dimes);
       System.out.printf("Number of Nickels: %4d  %n", Nickels);
       System.out.printf("Number of Pennies: %4d  %n", Pennies);
    //Prints out final number of coins used by type of coin.
   }//end of else
  }while(input>0);//end of do while

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make one while loop and keep referring to it until input < 0. So technically, all your calculations should go inside this huge while loop